# Como escanear datos de un fichero de manera precisa

Tags: c

Necesito sacar datos del apartado de marcajes (todo separado con tab) pero no se como sacarlo de manera precisa para luego hacer operaciones como sumar 1 hora o sacar cuanto tiempo tardaron

```
08:00   Julia   Gonzalez    8:45E 14:50S
06:00   Antonio Lopez Herrera   8:00E 14:45S 16:00E 17:00S
07:36   Maria   Perez Alonso    8:00E 14:45E 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Andrés  Gomez   8:05E 14:45S 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Sara    Martinez Conde  8:00E 14:45S 15:30E 16:45S 18:00E 20:00S
```

Y este es el codigo que he conseguido:

```
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    char A[100],hora[100],nombre[100],apellidos[100];


FILE *fichero;
fichero=fopen("Hola2.txt","r");
fgets(A,100,fichero);

while(fscanf(fichero,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t",hora,nombre,apellidos)==3){

}
}

fclose(fichero);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema de C, sino de manejo de cadenas. El problema es que tu archivo de entrada no guarda un formato estandarizado, a veces el nombre constan de 2 palabras y a veces de 3, y a veces tienes 2 lecturas de tiempo y a veces 4, yo empezaría por ordenar los datos, leer la cadena como texto y recortarla en partes y ordenarlas como nombre u horas. Hice un código que separa cada renglón en cadenitas, una vez identificada cada parte ya se pueden hacer cálculos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fichero;

int main(){
  char hora[7][10], nombre[3][20], A[100], *paso;
  int i,j,n=0,h=0,siga=1;

  fichero=fopen("Hola.txt","r");
  while (fgets(A,100,fichero) > 0){
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) hora[i][0]=0x00;
    for (j=0; j<3; j++) nombre[i][0]=0x00;
    i=0;j=0;h=0;n=0;

    strcpy (hora[0], strtok (A,"\t"));
    h++;
    strcpy (nombre[0], strtok (NULL,"\t"));
    n++;
    paso= strtok (NULL,"\t");
    while(paso){
      if(!strcmp(paso,"")) siga=0;
      if(paso[0]>='0' && paso[0]<='9'){
        strcpy(hora[h],paso);
        h++;
      }
      if(paso[0]>='A' && paso[0]<='Z'){
         strcpy(nombre[n],paso);
         n++;
      }
      paso= strtok (NULL,"\t");
    }
    printf(">> %-10.10s %-10.10s %-10.10s %-7.7s %-7.7s %-7.7s %-7.7s %-7.7s %-7.7s %-7.7s\n",
           nombre[0], nombre[1], nombre[2], hora[0], hora[1], hora[2], hora[3], hora[4], hora[5], hora[6]);
  }
  fclose(fichero);
}
```

El resultado es:

```
>> Julia     Gonzalez             08:00   8:45E   14:50S                                
>> Antonio   Lopez      Herrera   06:00   8:00E   14:45S  16:00E  17:00S                
>> Maria     Perez      Alonso    07:36   8:00E   14:45E  15:30E  17:00S                
>> Andris    Gomez      Alonso    08:00   8:05E   14:45S  15:30E  17:00S                
>> Sara      Martinez   Conde     08:00   8:00E   14:45S  15:30E  16:45S  18:00E  20:00S
```